# how do i make a video play with no sound until clicked on in html?

Tags: html, css

I have searched everywhere and can not find a way to make a video in html play with no sound until clicked on kinda like Facebook.

Answer (score 5):

The `autoplay` attribute will autoplay a video, and the `muted` attribute will mute a video by default. So that will play the video with no sound. Then you can assign a JS click handler to the video and turn off muting by setting `video.muted = false`

```js
var video = document.getElementById('video');
video.addEventListener('click',function() {
  video.muted = false;
});
```

```html
<video id="video" src="http://www.w3schools.com/html/mov_bbb.mp4" autoplay muted controls></video>
```